# Using 'updateMask().not()' in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, extract-by-mask

I am trying to mask out part of an image(tiff) with another image(tiff) using the 'updateMask' in google earth engine but I keep getting an empty output. The '.not()' is supposed to give the opposite of the output. I want the cleanup to be masked out from the ndviFinal

```js
Map.setCenter(-2.063,6.088,12)

//Importing SENTINEL-2 collection 
var St2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
    .filterDate('2015-01-01','2020-07-15')
    .filterBounds(galamsey_aoi)
    .select(['B1','B2','B3','B4','B8','B9','B11','B12'])
      .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',5))
      .median()
      .clip(galamsey_aoi);

//Display SENTINEL-2 image
var s2_palette = {bands: ['B11', 'B8', 'B4'], min:300, max: 4550}; // specify false color palette
Map.addLayer(St2,s2_palette,'Sentinel 2 (2015-2020)', false);


// NDVI Composite
var ndvi = St2.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']);

var ndvi1 = ndvi.gt(0.3).not().selfMask();

var ndvi2 = ndvi.lte(0.018).and(ndvi.gt(-0.07));

var ndviFinal = ndvi2.blend(ndvi1).selfMask();


//Preparing masking

//Adding an ID to a feature collection
var addID = function(feature) {
  return feature.set({id: 1});
};

// Map the ID function over the FeatureCollection and converting to Image (osm settlement).
var osm_settlement = osm_settlement.map(addID)
                    .reduceToImage({
                    properties:['id'],reducer:ee.Reducer.first()
                    }
                    );
                    
//Clipping osm_settlement to project area
var mask1 = osm_settlement.clip(galamsey_aoi)


//Creating a buffer of 40m 
var buffer = function(feature) {
  return feature.buffer(40);
};
var road_buffer = table.map(buffer)

var road = road_buffer.map(addID)
                    .reduceToImage({
                    properties:['id'],reducer:ee.Reducer.first()
                    }
                    );
                    

//Merging or combining all the mask
var cleanup = mask1.blend(builtup).blend(road).mask().clip(galamsey_aoi).selfMask();
Map.addLayer(cleanup,{min:0 , max:1, palette:['yellow']},'cleanup', false)
Map.addLayer(builtup,{min:0 , max:1, palette:['yellow']},'builtup', false)

print(builtup)
print(ndviFinal,"ndviFinal")

// Creating of final mask
var maskComposite = ndviFinal.updateMask(cleanup.not()).selfMask()

//Display of NDVI composite
Map.addLayer(ndviFinal, {min:0, max:1,  palette:['green']},'ndviFinal', false)
Map.addLayer(maskComposite, {min:0, max:1,  palette:['red']},'maskComposite', false)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/60f9cc570c405145c1e572ce8efd9384

Comment: `Image.load: Image asset 'users/mamponsah91/set' not found` in order to help you should share that image or make a proxy image to be able to reproduce the error

Comment: I have shared the image in the link below. Thank you https://code.earthengine.google.com/60f9cc570c405145c1e572ce8efd9384

Comment: How do i convert unsigned int8 data type to  int data type in google earth engine

Answer (score 1):

Masks ain't supposed to be self masked. The layer `cleanup` has pixels with value 1 and other pixels masked, so when you inverse using `.not()` you get pixels with value 0 and other pixels masked. Therefore, when you apply that mask, you get all pixels masked.

You have to unmask `cleanup`:

`var maskComposite = ndviFinal.updateMask(cleanup.unmask().not())`

https://code.earthengine.google.com/cd28e0647e0c0b40125c518fd55b7177

Comment: Thank you Rodrigo

Comment: This might be a bit beside the question, but a simpler solution would of been replacing the gt() function with lte() which would be the opposite of gt(), same as using .not()